A few questions (and attempted ans.) on Parsha Miketz. Thoughts welcome
Parshas Miketz

Yosef cried in private when he heard that Binyomin had 10 sons and he named them all after Yosef's life. Why did Binyomin do that? Isn't it a bit extreme? He barely knew Yosef, he was only about 10 years old when he saw him. So he was the only full brother, maybe name one son, but why all his kids?
Perhaps answer is, that Binyomin owed it to Yosef, because one reason for Yosef's name is yosef Hashem li ben acher, it was Rachel's tefila that birthed Binyomin based on Yosef's name, so if Yosef was "named after" Binyomin then it's only right for him to name all of his sons after Yosef, k'ilu they only exist because of Yosef's name.

In the beginning of the parsha after Yosef interprets the dream, the posuk says vayitav hadovor beeyney paroy uveyney KOL AVODOV. In what way could the servants possibly have found this interpretation good? They didn't have the dream themselves to feel it was right. They didn't see the interpretation in real life because it didn't happen yet. So how exactly was it yitav be'eyneyhem. They had absolutely nothing to base the chalom or the prison onto. As far as they know, there wasn't even any dream?



This should be split into two posts.
